# Swift Delegate Method Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I’m working through Ray Wenderlich’s iOS Apprentice book and is stuck in the second project. In `ListDetailViewController`, I have a button that calls the function `done()`. This function works as it prints "Done button is clicked". However, `ListDetailViewController` does not segue back to `AllListsTableViewController`.

I suspect this is because the delegate method, `listDetailViewControllerDidAdd` is not being called by the `done()` function. My reasoning is that `listDetailViewControllerDidAdd` method does not print "Done button called delegate method" therefore `done()` does not call the delegate method. Is this reasoning correct? If yes, why is that?

I have checked other questions on SO and most answers point to unassigned `delegate` value. However, I have already assigned `delegate` in `func prepare(for segue: )`. The following are the codes.

**ListDetailViewController.swift**

```
 protocol ListDetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func listDetailViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: ListDetailViewController)
    func listDetailViewControllerDidAdd(_ controller: ListDetailViewController, didFinishAdding checklist: Checklist)
    func listDetailViewControllerDidEdit(_ controlelr: ListDetailViewController, didFinishEditing checklist: Checklist)
}


class ListDetailViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    weak var delegate: ListDetailViewControllerDelegate?
    var checklistToEdit: Checklist?

    @IBAction func done() {
        if let checklist = checklistToEdit {
            checklist.name = textField.text!
            delegate?.listDetailViewControllerDidEdit(
                self,
                didFinishEditing: checklist)
        } else {
            let checklist = Checklist(name: textField.text!)
            delegate?.listDetailViewControllerDidAdd(
                self,
                didFinishAdding: checklist)
            print("Done button is clicked")
            print("\(checklist.name)")
        }
    }

}
```

**AllListsTableViewController.swift**

```
class AllListsTableViewController: UITableViewController, ListDetailViewControllerDelegate {    

func listDetailViewControllerDidAdd(_ controller: ListDetailViewController,
                                  didFinishAdding checklist: Checklist) {
        print("Done button called delegate method" )

        let newRowIndex = lists.count
        lists.append(checklist)
        
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newRowIndex, section: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowChecklist" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! CheckListViewController
            controller.checklist = sender as? Checklist
        } else if segue.identifier == "AddChecklist" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! ListDetailViewController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
}
```

What are the steps do you recommend to investigate and solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I haven't written code for iOS for more than a year, but I think the problem is the following line.  let controller = segue.destination as! ListDetailViewController

Comment: Besides, don't force-unwrap a variable.

Comment: Is `controller.delegate = self` called? "most answers point to unassigned delegate value" simply test it, do `print("delegate: \(delegate)")` where you do `print("\(checklist.name)")`.

Comment: Printing the delegate value shows that it is actually `nil`. Why is that?

Comment: Is `let controller = segue.destination as! ListDetailViewController; controller.delegate = self` even called?

Comment: I found the root of the issue. My `segue.identifier` is actually the wrong value. I have clicked the segue on Storyboard and change it to `AddChecklist`. Voila, it works. Thanks @Larme for pointing out the `nil` delegate value!